# Fancybox img-background and closing bug

Tags: html, css, background, controller, fancybox

on my website: http://evoxity.net/en/wallpaper/3-wallpaper.html

i noticed two bugs with fancy box. The first one is, if you decide to enlarge the pciture with a click on it. The first time it loads, the background is a bit out of the center, if you close the window and enlarge it again, its fine. This bug contains if you hover one of the sites of the fancybox and switch through the images.

The secound bug is, the line under the X to close the window.

Any suggestions how to fix that?

product.tpl:

```
{else}
                                            href="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, 'thickbox_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"
                                            data-fancybox-group="other-views"
                                            class="fancybox{if $image.id_image == $cover.id_image} shown{/if}"
```

global.css:

```
.fancybox-skin {
  background: #f4f5f7 !important; }

.fancybox-skin .fancybox-close {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f4f5f7!important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px; }
  .fancybox-skin .fancybox-close:hover {
    color: #515151; }
  .fancybox-skin .fancybox-close:after {
    content: "\f057";
    font-family: "FontAwesome"; }
```

Here some pictures to explain the last bug. (just click first, secound image to navigate) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzww4.jpg

Comment: There is a difference between "a fancybox bug" and your added code bugs :/

Comment: its not like i would say its a bug by fancybox. Its just a bug of my fancybox and i have no idea where it comes from. I didnt even add the paypal thing, thats default by prestashop so blame them and not me. Rly weird to go that hard on it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

search in global.css line 7959 add text-decoration:none;

Comment: Hey there, i checked the template folder and could just dinf contend of the fancybox in global.css and product.tpl so i edited it into the first post. I also disabled CCC. Could you explain me where this code is located?

Comment: Gosh, why would i search there? :D Anyways, now that is solved. Is the background moving bug also located in the paypal.css?

Comment: or glogal.css line 7959 add text-decoration:none;

Comment: No, you can override it and global.css

Comment: Here some pictures to explain the last bug. (just click first, secound image to navigate) http://imgur.com/kGUyv2i,Ts8rrOk#0

Comment: did not quite understand what you want, but I can assume that you have in mind about this lightbox navigation buttons, they are corrected in a file called jquery.fancybox.css styles since the 110th row

Comment: also regulated position button closure

Comment: Im not sure if we talk about the same @Alex Wilson. If you open the imgur link and focus your eye on the left border of it, you can clearly see that the background is moving between the both pictures. That is simply to simulate if you open the product like i provided in my start post, open the fancybox and slide with the site buttons.

Comment: to make it a bug or not provide a link to the developer or the original example of this plugin, it is possible to effect when browsing

Answer (score 0):

Removing the lines under the X

```
a {text-decoration: none;}
```

The box looks centered for me when I open it.

Comment: Its not about the box, the container on the background is done by the wallpaper and if I open the fancybox, the wallpaper gets a bit more to the right instead of keep the centered position.  I also disabled CCC so its easyer to help me. Could you tell me where this is located? Ill edit content where fancybox is in in tmy first post.